# Find command returning unexpected output on solaris

Tags: linux, search, find, solaris

I am currently experiencing issues with the find command, and I am unsure as to what is happening.
I am running this on OpenSolaris11 [Nexenta Storage device].

If I use:

```
find /volumes/stor01/home/home/user  -name "*.abc" -exec ls -al {} \;
```

or

```
find /volumes/stor01/home/ -name "*.abc" -exec ls -al {} \;
```

I get the expected return [I have nestled a file in the users home area. The /home location totaling about 3TB

However, this is where it starts getting strange. If I go up another directory, to the /volumes/stor01/ [about 12TB], I start seeing errors, and neither is the expected file displayed, however i enter any of the respective folders listed below it all works fine:

```
find /volumes/stor01 -name "*.abc" -exec ls -al {} \;
find: /volumes/stor01/storage/.zfs/shares: No such file or directory
find: /volumes/stor01/storage/rsync_27thMay10am: No such file or directory
find: /volumes/stor01/storage/.$EXTEND: No such file or directory
find: /volumes/stor01/storage/storage: No such file or directory
find: /volumes/stor01/VM_Backups: No such file or directory
find: /volumes/stor01/.mapping.0: No such file or directory
find: /volumes/stor01/scratch: No such file or directory
find: /volumes/stor01/VMWareStore: No such file or directory
find: /volumes/stor01/notes: No such file or directory
find: /volumes/stor01/.mapping.2: No such file or directory
find: /volumes/stor01/development: No such file or directory
find: /volumes/stor01/source: No such file or directory
find: /volumes/stor01/nim1: No such file or directory
find: /volumes/stor01/office: No such file or directory
find: /volumes/stor01/applications: No such file or directory
find: /volumes/stor01/.mapping.1: No such file or directory
find: /volumes/stor01/.$EXTEND: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What are those files?  Dangling soft links?

Comment: No. Most of them are actually further folders [ZFS shares to be more precise], ie:
     storage
     VM_Backups
     VMWareStore
     development
and so forth.
If I do any of the folders individually, everything works fine...

Comment: OK, Try running it under `truss` to see what system call is actually getting `ENOENT`:  `truss -f -vall -o /path/to/output/file find ...`.  Then search through the output file, such as `grep VMWareStore .../output/file`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, generating the truss log now. However I am wondering why the actual file does not get listed? Anyways, I will update later/tomorrow and thanks for the help.

Comment: Turns out I had enabled the visibility of the snapshot folder, and the special charachters looked like they were making find fall over. Hid this again and all is working.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had enabled the visibility of the snapshot folder, and the special charachters looked like they were making find fall over. Hid this again and all is working.